# Split index on filename gives me wrong output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, google-colaboratory

The structure of my folder and file looks like this

```
images = glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/input/final_data/)
```

Inside the final_data I have a couple of files say crash_039.jpg etc. Here I am splitting the part before underscore as my class and the whole part as my image.

I expect my output to have the class names without those square brackets. The code below gives me square brackets and I am not sure what is the issue or is this normal in collab?

```
images = glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/input/final_data/*.jpg")
train_image = []
train_class = []
for i in tqdm(range(len(images))):
    # creating the image name
    train_image.append(images[i].split('/')[7])
    # creating the class of image
    train_class.append(images[i].split('/')[7].split('_')[:1])
    
# storing the images and their class in a dataframe
train_data = pd.DataFrame()
train_data['image'] = train_image
train_data['class'] = train_class

# converting the dataframe into csv file 
train_data.to_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab/input/train_output/train_new.csv',header=True, index=False)
```

output

```
    image   class
0   crash_039.jpg   [crash]
1   crash_040.jpg   [crash]
```

expected output

```
    image   class
0   crash_039.jpg   crash
1   crash_040.jpg   crash
```

[image]

The attached image shows how the csv is storing it but I do not want those quotations and brackets around the class column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing like you are doing `images[i].split('/')[7].split('_')[:1])` returns you a list which you are printing.

I believe you want to use Index to get classname: `images[i].split('/')[7].split('_')[0])`

This solves your problem, however I suggest you to use `os.path.basename(filename)` instead of the messy `split('/')` you are doing.